# why does pushMode require the consumption of input?

Tags: antlr4

I have the following antlr4 lexer grammar with the goal to produce a token STRING_MODE from a string if the string doesn't start with '-'.

I am using the [testAssertion code](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4/blob/84087334d80af684582c9bbb233b62b3efc68183/tool/test/org/antlr/v4/test/PositionAdjustingLexer.g4) to implement a look ahead test.

Since I would like to add a lot more code to the lexer for strings itself and would like to add other prefixes than just '-' where different rules apply, i would like to immediately push a mode and continue the lexing there.

```
lexer grammar StrStrLexer;

@members {
  public boolean testAssertion(int assertionMode, int passingRule) {
  int index = _input.index();
  int mark = _input.mark();
  try {
     LexerATNSimulator interp = new LexerATNSimulator(this, _ATN, _decisionToDFA, _sharedContextCache);
     interp.copyState(_interp);
     int result = interp.match(_input, assertionMode);
     return result == passingRule;
   } finally {
     _input.seek(index);
     _input.release(mark);
   }
}

DETECT  : { testAssertion(DETECT_STRING,DETECT_STRING_PASS) }? ->
                   pushMode(STRING);

mode DETECT_STRING;

DETECT_STRING_PASS: ~[-];
DETECT_STRING_FAIL: .;

mode STRING;

STRING_MODE  : .+;
```

With this grammar receive for each input character error messages like:

```
token recognition error at: 'X'
```

If I rewrite the grammar and remove the pushMode it works fine:

```
lexer grammar StrStrLexer;

@members {
  public boolean testAssertion(int assertionMode, int passingRule) {
  int index = _input.index();
  int mark = _input.mark();
  try {
     LexerATNSimulator interp = new LexerATNSimulator(this, _ATN, _decisionToDFA, _sharedContextCache);
     interp.copyState(_interp);
     int result = interp.match(_input, assertionMode);
     return result == passingRule;
   } finally {
     _input.seek(index);
     _input.release(mark);
   }
}

STRING_MODE  : { testAssertion(DETECT_STRING,DETECT_STRING_PASS) }? .+;

mode DETECT_STRING;

DETECT_STRING_PASS: ~[-];
DETECT_STRING_FAIL: .;
```

Comment: Because [#687](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/687) (and [#688](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/688)). Note that we've found cases where users reported a bug to StackOverflow instead of the actual issue tracker, resulting in a 14 month delay in correcting the bug. When in doubt, post there first if you'd like to see something fixed eventually.

Comment: Thanks ! I wasn't sure if this was actually a bug, but next time i ll review the github issues first !